# Call view model method from view (xaml.cs)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a question on calling a method of view model from view (xaml.cs). Any suggestions would be appreciated.

The method works in view model since if I call the method in view model constructor, I will be able to see the data in DataGrid. But when I call the method in view (xaml.cs), the DataGrid is empty.

In the view part, I have the code snippet below: (xaml.cs part)

```
 private ShellViewModel viewModel = new ShellViewModel();

        public ShellView()

        {

             this.DataContext = viewModel;

             InitializeComponent();

        }

......

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

        {

             viewModel.Init();

        }// @@cannot call this method successfully
```

Comment: Define "successfully".

Comment: "@@cannot call this method successfully" means that when I click button, there is no data on DataGrid.

Comment: How not? Does it throw an exception? Does it not do what you were expecting it to do?

Comment: No it does not throw any exception. When I add code           MessageBox.Show("hello"); behind viewModel.Init();, a window will pop up showing "hello"

Comment: So it works? Without additional details about **what** doesn't work, you have zero chance of getting anything answered.

Comment: When viewModel.Init() is called, I cannot get data in DataGrid of view. Does the explanation make more sense?

Comment: Show us the view model or at least the Init() function and the views XAML code. Looks like your bindings aren't working... Whether it's the source that is not properly initialized, who knows

Comment: I added code snippet from view model (Note: Since the binding is not working, I hard-coded the parameters). The problem now is when I call Init() in view model constructor, the DataGrid in view shows the data. But if I remove Init() in constructor, no data is shown in view. Thanks. @BionicCode

Comment: Set your view's DataContext after InitializeComponent() method call.

Comment: You will never get any help if the only information provided is the assignment of the DataContext. This code snippet is useless and your question or problem very unclear. As Willem asked you before, please tell us what you're trying to do and what isn't working. And sore is relevant code please... This kind of questions are very annoying to me. Like a 12 years old ;)

Comment: ??? I don't understand you. Everything is working then. You said you invoked the Init() function and all its well andd if the function doesn't get called, the table remains empty. That's because your binding source is initialized in this method. You're creating the Table here... So where is the problem

Comment: Does your ViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged and does the ViewModel property triggers the PropertyChanged event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `View` you can have event handlers but what ever those handlers do, they  should only affect the view. So, I'd suggest you initialize your `ViewModel` e.g. in its own constructor.

But if you insist `viewModel.Init()` to be called after button is clicked, then bind your `Button` to a `ICommand` exposed from your ViewModel as property.

For example:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:ShellViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Button Command="{Binding InitCommand}">Init</Button>
```

---

```
public ShellViewModel()
{
    InitCommand = new RelayCommand(Init);
}

public ICommand InitCommand { get; private set; }

private void Init()
{
    throw NotImplementedException();
}
```